# Return status code 404 with JSON data for ASP WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm trying to return status code 404 with a JSON response, like such:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static dynamic Save(int Id)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    return new 
    {
        message = $"Couldn't find object with Id: {id}"
    };
}
```

But I keep getting HTML error page for 404 error instead of the JSON response. I've tried various of manipulating the `Response` with Flush, Clear, Write, SuppressContent, CompleteRequest (Not in order), but whenever I return 404 it still picks up the html error page.

Any ideas on how I can return a status code other than 200 OK (Since it's not ok, it's an error) and a JSON response?

I know I can throw an exception, but I'd prefer not to since it doesn't work with `customErrors mode="On"`

This is an older Website project in ASP.Net, and it seems most solutions in ASP MVC doesn't work.

Comment: if it's an error why not go for an InternalServerException. if it's an invallid parameter as in {id} why not go for a BadRequest.

When using System.Web.Http.ApiController it's especially easy you can just:
return InternalServerError(Exception) or return BadRequest(string)

Comment: Did you try to write into HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream ?
Or into HttpContext.Current.Response.Output (Output here is a TextWriter)

Comment: Just finished testing something else: In case you want to return a HttpResponseMessage use: return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "My message");

Comment: @Drag0nvil It's not an invalid parameter if it's an int, is it? My reasoning is that if I couldn't find an object (in the DB for example) with the Id supplied, it's an Object Not Found error. And `return InternalServerError(Exception)` doesn't work with this version of ASP WebSites sadly. And returning the HTTP status code for Internal Server Error will have the same effect as 404, it gives me a HTML page. Returning the status code for Bad Request only returns a text response "Bad request" and nothing else, so that sadly doesn't work either.

Comment: See my second post, when I used that on my REST server and tested it with postmen it would show the: "My message" in the body. if not then I'm sorry but your version/configuration is different the one I'm using.

Comment: @OleksandrTyshchenko Writing to Output or OutputStream doesn't seem to remove any of the HTML-page writing either. So unless there's some way to supress the HTML page from writing (Which I assumed SuppressContent did, but it doesn't) it won't work :(

Comment: @Drag0nvil Sadly can't find any CreateResponse on the Request object, will investigate if there's a similar method in my version/config

Comment: I seem to remember that you must set the status to OK first if you want to send an outputstream.  Otherwise flush will ignore it.

Comment: Well in that case I'm sorry I'm not quite sure myself then. Except maybe: did you enable complilation debug? that might be it. if not I do have some theories but those would just be guesses and you would probably be better of researching yourself ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually when you get he HTML error page that is IIS taking over the handling of the not found error.

You can usually bypass/disable this by telling the response to skip IIS custom errors.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static dynamic Save(int id) {
    //...

    //if we get this far return not found.
    return NotFound($"Couldn't find object with Id: {id}");
}

private static object NotFound(string message) {
    var statusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.StatusCode = statusCode;
    response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; //<--
    return new {
        message = message
    };
}
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver Nkosi, it worked perfectly! Skipping the custom errors only for these webmethods is not an issue since I don't see the purpose of having HTML errors as response to an AJAX request.